# Can SO reputation points be used to judge competence of a newbie coder?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I am self taught and my code is pretty horrible yet somehow I have over 300 points on this site from asking lots of questions. My question is can I use the relative points from each question as a guide to how I am improving?

Obviously a popular topic will gain more views and thus more prospect of votes but if its a poor question you might expect the up and down votes to even out or for it to be marked as a duplicate.

So, assuming I ask one question a day every day could I plot points against time and use the slope as an indication of my skill in coding? (assuming skill in asking questions == skill in coding).

Comment: You should rather plot the time difference between two subsequent questions ;)

Comment: Erm, not exactly.   Nothing wrong with being good at asking questions btw, knowing how to find help efficiently is a very marketable trait.

Comment: @Drdavidpier Or, perhaps that is feedback saying "No, reputation points can't be used to judge competence of a newbie coder" votes on meta are different.

Comment: @KevinB:  I'd like to think that an answer stating "No" with enough Unicode LTR markers would be *more* constructive than a downvote in this scenario, but to each their own.  The downvotes likely represent disagreement with the premise of the question, and there's a few things to take umbrage with (notably, the "question per day" thing).

Comment: To me, it seems absurd to have more than a few dozen or so questions once you are capable of debugging. At that point, you should be able to solve your problem before you are done formulating your question.

Comment: @KevinB:  You *really* should turn that into an answer.  It's pretty good.

Comment: I think this is getting down voted because it seems absurdly obvious that reputation correlates much more strongly with volume of interaction with the site than it does with ability

Comment: Probably rep can be a reasonable (albeit still rough) measure of how competent a user is at working properly with (maybe even sometimes "exploiting") the dynamics of the site. I think it could be taken as a little more than mere activity, since an ultra high rep user typically has some exceptionally good content in their repertoire and not just, say, 10,000 answers with 1 up-vote each. But I'm thinking like 100K user with way more answers than questions. In those cases, I'm inclined to just psychologically consider them expert programmers, to give them the benefit of the doubt.

Comment: Reputation is a measure of how much the system trusts you.

Comment: I've learned more by answering questions than by asking them, in that, I've become more cognizant of the experience on the answerer's side.  If you're looking at opportunities for growth, I think StackOverflow is as much a tool for learning how to communicate as it is a tool for the exchange of any given tidbit of technical knowledge.  Points probably correlate more with development in communication skill than in technical ability.

Answer (score 4):

> [C]an I use the relative points from each question as a guide to how I am improving?

If you like.  But I wouldn't put much value in that fact alone.

Reputation doesn't entirely correlate with programming skill or programming knowledge.  If you can ask a good question, or give a good answer, that's fantastic for the site, but it doesn't *prove* that you've improved or become better as a developer.

In fact, if you're asking a lot of questions, it could be argued that you're quite lost of a few concepts and that there is a regression of progress as opposed to any improvements.  You don't want *that* stipulation.

> (assuming asking questions == skill in coding)

There are users - who I won't name here - that have amassed quite a great deal of questions on the site.  If you read through say, 100 of them, would you be able to definitively prove that their skill in coding has improved since the first question they've asked?  Heck, [what about *my* questions?](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1079354/makoto?tab=questions)  Would one be able to see if my skills have improved or not just by looking at those?  (Honestly I'd say it's more or less that my toolbox has expanded, and not that I've become any more expert in one thing...)

Answer (score 3):

> (assuming skill in asking questions == skill in coding).

This is a false premise.

You can use your rep as a (very rough) measure at how good you are at asking questions.  That won't even correlate to how skilled you are at programming.

Comment: But... if I am skilled at asking questions it probably suggests that I understand what needs to be asked. Maybe this does not equate to skill in coding but maybe it shows understanding of the topic? Which must go some way towards skill at coding?

Comment: @Drdavidpier Asking questions equates to a *lack* of understanding of the topic.  If you understood the topic well you wouldn't need to ask the question.

Comment: Agreed, but asking a good question requires a lot more understanding than a poor question. Just look at the number of downvotes some new users get when they dont understand the fundamentals. Mind you a lot of votes get cast for lack of understanding of the site and how it works

Comment: @Drdavidpier A question can possibly require a strong understanding of certain concepts to be asked, most don't, but some do.  But all questions *necessitate* a lack of understanding of an important concept for the question to exist.  So no, you can't say that rep even correlates to a strong understanding of a topic.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect questions from someone who is getting better and better at coding to receive less and less upvotes, not more. While you may be getting better and better at asking questions, the questions you are asking should be getting more and more advanced meaning less and less people will find it interesting and useful. It will receive less traffic, and less traffic of course correlates to less voting activity.

Take a look at some of the most popular stackoverflow questions. The majority of them are the kind of problems that you only run into as a newbie developer; seasoned developers are already well past that point. They are popular because so many new developers have those problems, usually due to lack of coding skill (either in general, or with a particular language.)

Comment: If this is indeed the case then my question/assumption is valid i.e. point accrual per question can be used to judge competence. Its just the inverse of the example I gave.

Comment: That is a fair observation. though, I think it would be even better to also include the frequency of questions asked in the comparison.

Comment: There's one exception I think, and it's a bit controversial -- questions relating to design, and possibly somehow related to "best practices" (though perhaps tastefully not stating it as such explicitly). With experience comes that kind of natural progression from overcoming little debugging obstacles in daily code to tackling projects of grander scale and complexity, and then finding the difficulty shifting to design and maintainability (and design remaining difficult for the rest of our careers). Yet those Qs are somewhat discouraged (always grey zone of subjectivity).

Comment: ... yet I think that's a common evolution of one's questions (whether explicitly asked or not)... to go from a bunch that can be solved by knowledge of using a debugger, towards APIs and more domain-specific questions, and then towards designing architectures for large-scale codebases.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely an exception. questions that are subjective (not all subjective questions are off topic) are often popular among experts of a language because that's an area, like you said, that remains challenging even to experts. Questions of deployment processes, build processes, organization, compiler optimizations, etc.